# how to get invoked ant.exe path in the ant script

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Is there any way to get invoked ant.exe path in the ant script ? rather than the ant path set in environment variables. Using the env.ANT_HOME, one would get ant path in environmental variables, but that will not help me.

If  ant script  is invoked from "C:\Ant\bin\ant.exe", is there any way to get same path in ant script?

Answer (score 0):

> If ant script is invoked from "C:\Ant\bin\ant.exe", is there any way to get same path in ant script?

Yes. Assuming you are executing from above mentioned path, use "basedir" variable set to current working directory ie. where your script resides.

Something like this :

```
<project name="abc" default="test" basedir="." >
```

Comment: This wont work. If any ant executable file is invoked in ones development machine, ant.exe binary would change based on diferent configurations

Comment: This wont work. If any ant executable file is invoked in ones development machine, ant.exe binary would change based on diferent configurations.                                                                        1. ant.exe set in environment variable ant_home would be picked. (or) 2. ant.exe set in environment variable ant_home would be picked (or) 3. If user executes ant build file using qualified way like,  D:\Softwares\Ant\bin\ant.exe c:\build.xml

Comment: I meant if your build.xml is at the same location as that of ant.exe and you execute that build.xml, basedir will provide you path of where ant.exe is located. Here, basedir is the location where build.xml resides irrespective from where you execute